# Google Sign-in not working after releasing signed APK in Alpha testing

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I Had problem in sign in for google.
I had installed the release build manually its working , but if I install it from play store I am getting sign in failed.

> W/Auth: [Get Token] Get Token failed with status code: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
> E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE
>
> E/SignInActivity: Google Sign In failed.

Code snippet:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* 
OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Comment: i have only release sha1 key added to firebase

Comment: Did you download new google-services.json and add your project?

Comment: @AndroDevelopers i have faced same issue please share your solution?

Comment: go to fire base --> settings --> account linking ---> google play (Click Manage Linking) and click link google play account that's it. wait few minutes u will get Your App Working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As AndroDevelopers said in [this comment](/questions/44275676/google-sign-in-not-working-after-releasing-signed-apk-in-alpha-testing/45167491#comment76683724_44275676):

> go to fire base --> settings --> account linking ---> google play (Click Manage Linking) and click link google play account that's it. wait few minutes u will get Your App Working

It is help me.

Comment: brother you saved my life.Thank You very much.

Comment: Great. It's works for me, after waste my couple of hours got me one solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an account linking option