# google signin not working when distributed through playstore firebase oauth2

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

So, i created a signed apk with my key store, all the credentials/sha1 key on firebase and google api console matches to my release keystore. and the google signin is working when i externally install the generated apk.

but when i try to distribute it through playstore i am not able to sign in.

i updated the google servises.json, deleted the app on firebase and created once again, but its not working at all.

any idea where i am going wrong??
it would be much help if someone could answer as i am stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a silly mistake , while distributing I accidently opted for google playstore app signing. therfore the keyhash was changed for the apk distributed through playstore. used the new  sha1key on oauth admin page it worked

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this post:
[Link to original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275676/google-sign-in-not-working-after-releasing-signed-apk-in-alpha-testing)

[image]